# How do I create a random matrix in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on a project and it is asking me to create a random matrix in Swing. How do I go about creating a 10x10 window with numbers varying from 0-1?

I'm confused with how I set Swing up in Java.

Comment: You could use a `JTable`, but the most common requirement is to build some kind of model which contains the data you want to display, beyond that it just comes down to find the best components that meet your output/input requirements

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about specific problems in code. Do some research and make an attempt. If you are still having trouble, we will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a window with random numbers from 0 to 1, use this:

```
import javax.swing.*; // JFrame, JPanel, ...
import java.awt.*; // GridLayout

public class RandomMatrix10x10 extends JFrame { // This is the window class
    public static class RandomNumber extends JPanel { // This is the random number grid space class
        public RandomNumber() {
            JTextArea area = new JTextArea(); // This will contain the number
            area.setText(Double.toString(Math.random())); // This puts the number in place
            area.setEditable(false); // This prevents the user from changing the matrix
            this.add(area); // This puts the number into the gridspace
        }
    }

    public RandomMatrix10x10() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10)); // This makes the frame into a 10 x 10 grid
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            this.add(new RandomNumber()); // This puts all 100 numbers in place
        }
    }
}
```

To use, create an instance of the `RandomMatrix10x10` class like so:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new RandomMatrix10x10();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // 3
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) // 6
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, if I'm mistaken, and you only want 1 or 0 instead of a decimal in between, replace the line

> `area.setText(Double.toString(Math.random()));`

with the line

> `area.setText(Integer.toString((int) Math.round(Math.random()));`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! Do you know of how I could also do this in JavaFX?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use JavaFX, I'll try learning it and getting back to you ASAP.